# Function with custom Options and modified Options for built-in Symbols

Tags: functions, options

I couldn't find a more descriptive title, but I guess an example will explain my problem.

I set up some customized `Grid` function including some additional functionalities which I control with custom  Options. Additionally, I would like to change some of the standard `Grid` Options, e.g. always use `Frame->All`. Take the following working example:

```
Options[myGrid] = {Frame -> All, "Tooltip" -> False};
myGrid[content_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=
  Module[{con},
    If[OptionValue["Tooltip"],
      con = MapIndexed[Tooltip[#1, #2] &, content, {-1}],
      con = content
    ];
    Grid[con,
      Sequence @@ 
        FilterRules[{opts}~Join~Options[myGrid], Options[Grid]]
    ]
  ]
```

defining an example content:

```
mat = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
```

We can test the behavior:

```
myGrid[mat]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

The custom "Tooltip" flag works as intended. Now I want to pass an `Option` to `Grid`, that has not been explicitely set in the above `Options[myGrid]` declaration.This eventually makes it through to the Grid, but produces an error message.

```
myGrid[mat, Background -> Blue]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To get rid of the errors I embed the Options from Grid into my custom  function:

```
Options[myGrid] = 
  Join[
    {Frame -> All, "Tooltip" -> False},
    Options[Grid]
  ];
```

Now, I can change the Grid Options without raising an error:

```
myGrid[mat, Background -> Green]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

but the custom setting `Frame->All` gets lost.

```
myGrid[mat, Frame -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Apparently, the default `Frame->None` setting for `Grid` overrules my custom setting. I banged my head against this problem for too long already, therefore my plea for  your assistance.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

[OptionsPattern](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/OptionsPattern.html):

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Therefore declare `Options` for both `myGrid` and `Grid` as valid:

```
Options[myGrid] = {Frame -> All, "Tooltip" -> False};

myGrid[content_, opts : OptionsPattern[{myGrid, Grid}]] := . . .
```

Then:

```
myGrid[mat, Background -> Blue]
```

> ```
> Grid[mat, Background -> RGBColor[0, 0, 1], Frame -> All]
> ```

With no error message.

Comment: This is pretty cool, +1.

Comment: @Leonid I had no idea this was esoteric. :-)

Comment: This particular form is not documented (list of functions inside `OptionsPattern[]`). I wasn't aware of it.

Comment: @Leonid I put a copy of a line from the documentation at the top of my post.  Does it not describe this use?

Comment: This does indeed, but this is not what I see in the [V9 documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/OptionsPattern.html), where only list of rules is mentioned. I will try to remember to ask why there was such a change.

Comment: @Leonid It's right on that page, under **Details** -- I can see how that seems hidden.

Comment: Ok, you are right. My fault, then. In some sense, the placement is right in the docs.

Comment: Hi Mr.Wizard and @Leonid, instead of a separate question I will write it as a comment, unless you consider it is better not to. I have been using the method of this answer succesfully with buil-tin functions. But now imagine that Grid in the above example is one functon I wrote in package A and myGrid is a function I wrote in package B. Then this method returns an error message, that an option is unknown. When I evaluate myGrid *twice* then it works. You have an idea why?

Comment: @Santi Are you including package A in the `BeginPackage` expression in package B?

Comment: @Wizard yes I am using this: ` BeginPackage["PackageB`", {"PackageA`"}] `

Comment: I can't format very well the output here, but yes, I am not forgetting any "`" or something

Comment: I also declared the options for my custom "Grid" function in package A, using: option1::usage="..." before trhe Private context. That means that packageB can see the options of the function in package A.

Comment: @Santi (1) To escape code that includes a back-tick you must wrap it in double back-ticks.  (2) I suggest you post a new question with a minimal working example of both packages A and B.  To debug the problem I would need to start by recreating these myself and it would be better that it come from you so that it is genuinely representative.

Comment: Ok thanks! At the moment I don't have much time, but on the weekend I'll try to do the most suitable MWE that I can come up with.

Answer (score 6):

The problem in this particular case comes from the default setting of the `Dividers` option, which overrides the `Frame` option settings. This does not strike me as a right behavior, or at least these options are not as orthogonal as they should be. This appears to fix the problem:

```
Options[myGrid] = 
   Join[{Frame -> All, "Tooltip" -> False}, 
      DeleteCases[Options[Grid], Dividers -> _]];
```

On a general note, however, I would add all options you may ever want to pass to some functions inside your function, explicitly as valid options of your function. If you find this too bothersome, you can, for this particular function (`myGrid`), switch back to good old `OptionQ` pattern:

```
myGrid[content_, opts___?OptionQ] := ...
```

at the expense of the short "magical" version of  `OptionValue` not working any more, so you will have to use `OptionValue[myGrid,{opts},"Tooltip"]`. I do this sometimes, in exactly this sort of situations.

Comment: Any advantage of using `OptionQ` versus `OptionsPattern[]` if in any case you will end up using the longer versions of `OptionValue`?

Comment: @Rojo with my method you do not need the longer version of `OptionValue`.