# How to insert a function into OptionsPattern?

Tags: function-construction, options

I’ve written a function TableauForm to draw a standard Young Tableau. This problem is related to [this one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20470/function-with-custom-options-and-modified-options-for-built-in-symbols), however, the difficulty is that, a *function* has to be applied to the list in my case.

This is my first version code:

```
TableauForm [l : {{__} ..}, opts : OptionsPattern[{Alignment -> {Center, Center},FrameStyle -> Thin, Grid}]] := 
  Grid[l, 
  Frame -> {None, None, 
    Thread@Rule[Flatten[Function[{a, b}, {a, #} & /@ b] @@@ Transpose[{Range@Length@l, Range /@ Length /@ l}], 1], True]}, 
  Alignment -> OptionValue[Alignment], FrameStyle -> OptionValue[FrameStyle]];
```

The function works well when evaluate this:

```
youngTableau = {{1, 2, 3}, {4}};
TableauForm [youngTableau]
```

[image: first output]

Or even this:

```
TableauForm [youngTableau, FrameStyle -> {Red, Thin}]
```

[image: second output]

But the flaw is that if someone *doesn’t wants to show the lines* (regardless of such a strange usage of this function) and evaluate this

```
TableauForm [youngTableau, Frame->None]
```

The output will still draw up the lines just like the first one.

[image: first output]

I’ve put the drawing function into the `OptionsPattern`, but only make it worse

```
TableauForm [l : {{__} ..}, opts : OptionsPattern[{Alignment -> {Center, Center}, 
    Frame -> {None, None, (Thread@ Rule[Flatten[Function[{a, b}, {a, #} & /@ b] @@@ Transpose[{Range@Length@#, Range /@ Length /@ #}], 1], True] &)},FrameStyle -> Thin, Grid}]] := 
  Grid[l, Frame -> OptionValue[Frame],Alignment -> OptionValue[Alignment],FrameStyle -> OptionValue[FrameStyle]];
```

Now evaluating `TableauForm[youngTableau]` will give a table with empty frame.

[image]

To sum up and put the problem into another way, how to write a function sharing the same `OptionsPattern` with `Grid` only changing some default settings? (Note that some default settings may be a function of the parameters.) Is it possible to put a function into `OptionsPattern`, or are there any other ways to do this(plot a Young Tableau)?

Comment: This is because You are creating `Frame` independly of `FrameStyle`. You can use `, FrameStyle -> Transparent`

Comment: @Kuba I don't understand. Since in the normal case, I want to show the frame not make it transparent.

Comment: There is also no options connected to Frame in your `OptionsPattern`, add `, Frame -> Automatic,` to it and add the following to the `body`: `Frame -> If[OptionValue[Frame] =!= Automatic, OptionValue[Frame], {None, None, ...`

Comment: @Kuba Yes,this would work in this particular question. (Actually I've tried `If[OptionValue[Frame] =!= None, ...`,but my trial is not as good as yours)But the handling is not consistent with FrameStyle or others. And when applied to other functions with default settings `Automatic`,this solution will have to change again.

Comment: Why it is not consistent?

Comment: @Kuba I mean if I use the same method to such as `FrameStyle`, then running `TableauForm[...,FramStyle->Automatic]`, I hope to get the default `Grid` output but I will get a specified one. I think the solution is restricted to the case that the default setting is `None`; it will conflict with the options whose default setting is `Automatic`. That's why I think the solution is not universal.

Comment: Do not change anything for `FrameStyle`. Only `Frame`, it works for me with automatic or custom `FrameStyle`. Or maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: @Kuba Yes, as I said, it only works for `Frame`. I just take `FrameStyle` as an example (maybe not a proper example) to point out the possible flaws or restrictions. I'm looking for a more general way to handle this issue. It should work for all functions, all default `Rule` setting, just like the ordinary use of `OptionsPatten` in the documentation.