# Young Tableaux Miscellanea

Tags: combinatorics, compatibility, combinatorica

I have a problem which is mostly neatly described by using Young Tableaux.  Mathematica seems to have these Tableaux built in, except that the `Tableaux` function is only in Combinatorica.  When I `Needs[Combinatorica]` I get a warning suggesting that I look at the Compatability Guide for Combinatorica, which I can't seem to find.  Does anyone have a link, or know if any of the `Tableaux`-related functions are the problematic ones?

The Tableaux function itself is hardly documented at all, and its output is quite tough to read.  I am hoping there is a nice built-in way to draw the Tableaux in the nice YT in English notation (longest rows on top) [A custom drawing function is in [How to insert a function into OptionsPattern?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28765/how-to-insert-a-function-into-optionspattern) ].  Is there such a function?

Finally, can anyone explain what the format of the input to `Tableaux` should be?

Here are some examples that work:

```
In[1]:= Needs["Combinatorica`"]

    General::compat: Combinatorica Graph and Permutations functionality has been superseded by 
preloaded functionality. The package now being loaded may conflict with this. Please see 
the Compatibility Guide for details.

In[2]:= Tableaux[3]
Out[2]= {{{1, 2, 3}}, {{1, 3}, {2}}, {{1, 2}, {3}}, {{1}, {2}, {3}}}

In[3]:= Tableaux[{3}]
Out[3]= {{{1, 2, 3}}}

In[4]:= Tableaux /@ IntegerPartitions[3]
Out[4]= {{{{1, 2, 3}}}, {{{1, 3}, {2}}, {{1, 
    2}, {3}}}, {{{1}, {2}, {3}}}}
```

while something like `Tableaux[{1, 2, 3}]` gives errors.

Does `Tableaux[integer]` give all possible tableaux with `integer` entries?
Does `Tableaux[{int1, int2, ..., intk}]` give all possible tableaux of `k` rows of length `int1` ... `intk` respectively?  This would explain why `Tableaux[{1,2,3}]` throws errors---it would be a malformed tableaux.

Comment: Combinatorica documentation is unfortunately not included with Mathematica.  The detailed description is in [this book](http://books.google.com/books?id=AvUXQ98ynXUC).   Try to check google books for the relevant page or borrow it from your library, if you can. While Combinatorica is supposed to be obsolete, a significant part of its functionality is not yet built into Mathematica.  I'm not familiar with this topic so I can't tell you if this functionality is available elsewhere ...

Comment: Wow, I couldn't have asked for a better, yet more disappointing, answer.

Comment: @evanb: As Szabolcs said, that *is* the canonical reference, and even it is a bit sparse to be honest (though an excellent book). Steven makes himself quite available (I found this true when I found some inconsistencies in his Algo. book), might be worth a try pinging him, and IIRC you can peruse the source, figure it out from there.

Comment: That's good to know.  Maybe I will shoot him an email at some point next week...

Answer (score 4):

There are short description and the definition of the `Tableaux`:

```
Quiet@Needs["Combinatorica`"];
?? Tableaux
```

> `Tableaux[p]` constructs all tableaux having a shape given by integer partition `p`.

```
Attributes[Tableaux] = {Protected}

Tableaux[s_List] := 
 Module[{t = LastLexicographicTableau[s]}, 
  Table[t = NextTableau[t], {NumberOfTableaux[s]}]]

Tableaux[n_Integer?Positive] := Join @@ Tableaux /@ Partitions[n]
```

`` Combinatorica`Private` `` context was removed for clarity.

Also from [*Computational Discrete Mathematics*](http://books.google.com/books?id=AvUXQ98ynXUC):

The list of tableaux of shape `{2,2,1}`  illustrates the amount of freedom available to tableau structures. The smallest element is always in the upper left-hand corner, but the largest element is free to be the rightmost position of the last row defined by all the distinct parts of the partition.

```
Tableaux[{2,2,1}]
(* {{{1, 4}, {2, 5}, {3}}, {{1, 3}, {2, 5}, {4}}, 
 {{1, 2}, {3, 5}, {4}}, {{1, 3}, {2, 4}, {5}},{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5}}} *)
```

By iterating through the different integer partitions as shapes, all tableaux of a particular size can be constructed.

```
Tableaux[3]
(* {{{1, 2, 3}}, {{1, 3}, {2}}, {{1, 2}, {3}}, {{1}, {2}, {3}}} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're not worried about putting information into the boxes of your Young Tableaux, the FerrersDiagram function will do the job. It takes a partition {a,b,c,...} and prints the Young Diagram in 'dot' form, like in

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29#Ferrers_diagram

The Mathematica documentation is fairly minimal

http://reference.wolfram.com/language/Combinatorica/ref/FerrersDiagram.html

Comment: Hi ! Link only answers are usually frowned upon around these parts. If you can provide a minimum working example showcasing the functionality and explaining why it works, now, that would be great.

Comment: Alas, I would like to put data into the YT boxes.  The question now linked to in the question does a pretty good job.