# What's the best way to select compatible options?

Tags: options

How do i safely, efficiently, and elegantly select compatible options?

I normally do

```
foo[opts:OptionsPattern[]] := Module[
    {goodOpts},
    goodOpts = FilterRules[{opts}, Options[bar][[All,1]]];
    bar[goodOpts]
]
```

Is there any loophole where this can cause bugs?

Is there a more efficient and more elegant way?

Comment: I don't think there's any difference between that and `goodOpts=FilterRules[{opts},Options[bar]]`, and the assignment can be made in the first argument of module.

Comment: This is possibly a duplicate of [(353)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/353/121), especially my answer there.

Comment: Also for the reason described specifically in [(20470)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20470/121) you should be using `opts : OptionsPattern[{foo, bar}]` assuming `foo` itself takes options.

Answer (score 1):

I my opinion, this is exactly the way to go. As pointed out by Anon you can do the assignment directly in the variable list of `Module`, but otherwise it is equivalent to the example shown in the [Setting Up Functions with Optional Arguments](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/SettingUpFunctionsWithOptionalArguments.html) tutorial:

```
odeplot[de_, y_, {x_, x0_, x1_}, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Module[{sol},
  sol = NDSolve[de, y, {x, x0, x1}, 
    FilterRules[{opts}, Options[NDSolve]]];
  If[Head[sol] === NDSolve,
   $Failed,
   Plot[Evaluate[y /. sol], {x, x0, x1}, 
    Evaluate[FilterRules[{opts}, Options[Plot]]]]
   ]
  ]
```

A nice thing of `FilterRules` is that it even works with nested option lists, which is often possible in *Mathematica*

```
Plot[2 x, {x, 0, 1}, {ColorFunction -> Hue, {ColorFunctionScaling -> False}}]
```

This will then even work with your example

```
foo[opts : OptionsPattern[]] := FilterRules[{opts}, Options[Plot]]
foo[{ColorFunction -> Hue, {ColorFunctionScaling -> False, {MaxIterations -> 30}}}]
```

Comment: halirutan, do you feel that this question is *not* a duplicate?  I intend(ed) to close it but since you felt it deserved an answer I don't want to be rude.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard No, I agree with you, but I wanted to point out, that this is exactly as it is suggested by the documentation. I wouldn't mind if you close it and then people still would find this specific information here *and* would have a link to the more general topic about how to set up functions with options. Can closed questions be found by everyone?

Comment: Okay, I think I'll do that in a while. (That gives other people a change to voice an opinion or post an answer if they feel inclined.)  Yes, closed or at least duplicate questions should be visible to all and appear in searches; it is one of their functions.

Comment: The documenation for `FilterRules` says it try to match against the LHSs:

("FilterRules[rules,patt] filters the list rules by picking out only those rules >whose left-hand sides match patt.
FilterRules[rules,{Subscript[patt, 1],Subscript[patt, 2],\[Ellipsis]}] picks out >rules whose left-hand sides match any of the Subscript[patt, i].")

So should not the usage be `Sequence@@FilterRules[{opts}, Options[f][[All,1]]]`
instead of `Sequence@@FilterRules[{opts}, Options[f]]` ?

Comment: @red3y3 Yes, but when you look in the *Details* section of the documentation to `FilterRules` you find the following statement: *If any of the Subscript[patt, i] is a rule of the form lhs->rhs, then it is treated the same as lhs.* Therefore, giving rules does work too.