# How do I override options with my own defaults?

Tags: functions, options, optional-arguments

I'm calling a function `f` from within a function `g` and would like to pass any valid options for `f` to `g`, replacing some (say, `optA` and `optB`) with defaults different from those defined for `f`.

What is the right way to do this?

I can get things to (seemingly) work with

```
Options[g] = Join[FilterRules[Options[f], Except[optA | optB]], {optA -> 0, optB -> 0}];
g[x, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
    f[x, opts, OptA -> OptionValue[OptA], optB -> OptionValue[optB]]
```

but this looks pretty verbose to me. Is there a better, more idiomatic, way?

Comment: This is how I usually do it except for the minor difference of writing it as `Options[g] = Options[f]; SetOptions[g, {optA -> 0, optB -> 0}]` (instead of filtering).  The most annoying thing for me about this solution is that if I later `SetOptions` on `f`, the change won't be inherited by `g`.  But this is what happens with builtins too (e.g. `Plot` vs `Graphics`) and the workaround is rather verbose and complicated.

Comment: @Szabolcs: So the explicit `OptA -> OptionValue[OptA], optB -> OptionValue[optB]` in the call to `f` is indeed necessary?

Comment: Related: [(20470)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20470/121)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I must've forgotten about that discussion when posting my answer here. I have added a link to it to my answer.

Comment: @Leonid Surely I have forgotten more, but thank you. :-)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here is what I do in such cases ([*edit from 01/10/2020 - apparently, this technique has been exposed on this site earlier, at least partially, in [this nice answer by Mr.Wizard](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/20475) - which I definitely read but must have forgotten at the time of posting my answer*]) :

```
ClearAll[g, f];
Options[f] = {optA -> 1, optB -> 1, optC -> 1};
f[x_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
   {OptionValue[optA], OptionValue[optB], OptionValue[optC]}

Options[g] = {optA -> 0, optB -> 0};
g[x_, opts : OptionsPattern[{g, f}]] := f[x, opts, Sequence @@ Options[g]]
```

In other words, only define options for `g` which belong to `g`, and inherit other options from `f` via the argument of `OptionsPattern`. Also, pass all options of `g` explicitly in the call to `f`, as in  `Sequence @@ Options[g]`. The fact that they come after `opts` means that they will be over-ridden by `opts`, as they should be.

Examples:

```
g[1]

(* {0, 0, 1} *)

g[1, optA -> 2]

(* {2, 0, 1} *)
```

The added advantage of this scheme is that it is free from the flaw mentioned by Szabolcs, in that subsequent changes of `Options[f]` will be picked up in this method automatically.

Comment: This is a great solution, but I can't get it to work for me in practice. I get errors deep in my code about some options not being valid. I'll see if I can generate an M(N)WE.

Comment: I was at a loss for how to do exactly this, your answer helped me a lot!

Comment: @gpap Thanks! I am glad this was helpful. This is one of the things that are not very easy to infer from the docs, although all bits and pieces are there.

Answer (score 4):

Trick that I sometimes find useful is "inheriting" of default option value from another symbol using delayed rule like:

```
optName :> OptionValue[anotherSymbol, optName]
```

With `f` defined as:

```
ClearAll[f];
Options[f] = {optA -> 1, optB -> 1, optC -> 1};
f[x_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := OptionValue[{optA, optB, optC}]
```

We can define `g` in following way:

```
ClearAll[g];
(* Inherit all options from f *)
Options[g] = # :> OptionValue[f, #] & @@@ Options[f];
(* Change default values of some of them. *)
SetOptions[g, optA -> 0, optB -> 0];
g[x_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := f[x, opts, Options[g]]
```

Basically it works as previous solutions

```
g[x]
(* {0, 0, 1} *)
g[x, optA -> 2, optC -> 2]
(* {2, 0, 2} *)
```

`g` inherits options from `f` in all situations, not only in above specific function call.

```
OptionValue[g, {optA, optB, optC}]
(* {0, 0, 1} *)
```

If you change default options of `f`, then non-overridden default options of `g` will inherit this change in all circumstances:

```
SetOptions[f, optC -> 2];
g[x]
(* {0, 0, 2} *)
OptionValue[g, {optA, optB, optC}]
(* {0, 0, 2} *)
```

Also at any time you can decide to change default value of any option (not only those overridden when g was defined) only on `g` without affecting `f`.

```
SetOptions[g, optC -> 0];
g[x]
(* {0, 0, 0} *)
f[x]
(* {1, 1, 2} *)
```

You can also, at any time, decide to use inherited option value:

```
SetOptions[g, optA :> OptionValue[f, optA]];
g[x]
(* {1, 0, 0} *)
```