# About the OptionsPattern[] approach of inheriting Options

Tags: options, argument-patterns

Szabolcs showed in this [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/140912/4742), that there are possibly two approaches to inherit function options. He recommended the `Join` approach. At first, I agreed. But today I found this approach can cause problem if we don't take care.

For example, If you have a function `f` with options set as

```
Options[f] = {...};
```

and you also have a bunches of function g,h,p,q,... that all inherit options from `f` via `Join`. That is

```
Options[g]=Join[...,Options[f]]
```

etc. Then what if you change the `Options` of `f`? Then you have to find all function g,h,p,q,... that inherit from `f`, and reevaluate their definition. This kind of evaluation dependency of function definition is kind of not reasonable.

So I turned to `OptionsPattern[]` approach. It doesn't have the above problem. But it got its own problems. The small problem is that `SyntaxInformation` needs special care, and need to use undocumented `OptionNames`. This one is relatively easy to tackle, [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/160275/4742) is my attempt to auto the setting process of `SyntaxInformation`

While the bigger problem of `OptionsPattern[]` approach is due to `Options` function. The Mathematica designed `Options` function to be that can only show explicit default options, not those hidden in `OptionsPattern[]`. For example,

```
ClearAll[f];
Options[f]={opt1->1};
f[x_,opts:OptionsPattern[{f,Plot}]]:=...
```

Evalute `Options[f]` can only give you `{opt1->1}`. However, the true available options of `f` should be all `Plot` options plus `{opt1->1}`. This behaviour of `Options` makes inheritance impossible. Because somewhere in another function `g` that inherit `f` must use `FilterRules`. For example

```
ClearAll[g];
g[y_,opts:OptionsPattern[{g,f}]]:=f[y,FilterRules[{opts},Options[f]]
```

However, the above definition is wrong. Because, `Options[f]` is incomplete!. What is more, due to `Options` behaviour, `OptionsPattern` got problems too Because according to the doc, `OptionsPattern[{f}]` is equivalent to `Options[f]`, so `OptionsPattern[{g,f}]` is also incomplete.

So my thought is that to make `OptionsPattern[]` works properly. **We need two additional function `trueOptions` and the corresponding `trueOptionsPattern`**. The `trueOptions` should give all available options including those hidden in `OptionsPattern`, so `trueOptions[f]` equals correctly `Plot` options plus `{opt1->1}`. And `trueOptionsPattern[f]` treated as obtained from `trueOptions[f]`. So we can use the `OptionsPattern` approach to inherit.

```
ClearAll[g];    
g[y_,opts:trueOptionsPattern[{g,f}]]:=f[y,FilterRules[{opts},trueOptions[f]]
```

Unfortunately, Mathematica doesn't provide such functions

`tureOptions` seems easier to implement, for example

```
ClearAll[getOptionsPatternContent];
getOptionsPatternContent::noDownValue = 
  "`1` got no DownValue. It probably not defined";
getOptionsPatternContent[symbol_] := Module[{},
   funcForm = If[DownValues[symbol] === {},
     Message[getOptionsPatternContent::noDownValue, symbol]; Abort[],
     FullForm[
      Cases[DownValues[symbol] /. 
         Verbatim[symbol][x___] :> nullHead[x], nullHead[___], 
        Infinity][[1]]]; 
     optionsPatternContent = 
      Complement[
       Flatten@Cases[funcForm, Verbatim[OptionsPattern][x_] :> x, 
         Infinity], {symbol}]]];

ClearAll[trueOptions];
trueOptions[symbol_] := Module[{optionsPatternContent},
  optionsPatternContent = getOptionsPatternContent[symbol];
  DeleteDuplicates@
   Flatten@Join[
     If[optionsPatternContent === {}, {}, 
      Table[If[Head@i === Rule, i, trueOptions@i], {i, 
        optionsPatternContent}]], Options@symbol]]
```

But **how to implement a `trueOptionsPattern[]`?** A naive try

```
ClearAll[trueOptionsPattern];
trueOptionsPattern[] := OptionsPattern[];
trueOptionsPattern[x_] := 
  OptionsPattern[
   Flatten@Table[If[Head@i === Rule, i, trueOptions@i], {i, x}]];
```

is not working. Because `trueOptionsPattern[{g,f}]` needs `g`, but `g` is not defined yet.

What is more? `OptionsPattern[]` seems has some subtleties with `OptionValue`, so I am not sure whether this line of thought will work. Any suggestions and comments?

Comment: Have you seen [my answer to "How do I override options with my own defaults?" question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/67436/14303)? Basically you have all options listed in `Options[g]`, but you can still inherit default option values from `f` in runtime.

Comment: Hi, @jkuczm What if we add new options of `f`?

Comment: You could use delayed assignment like `Options@g := Options@f`, but first call to `SetOptions[g, ...]` will assign an explicit list of options, so maintaining inheritance from, possibly changing, `Options@f` would require `UpValues` overriding `SetOptions[g, ...]`.

Comment: As a general note: whether you want function to inherit default values of other function is of course your design decision, but it's inheritance that increases coupling, not lack of inheritance. What you describe as "evaluation dependency of function definition" in "`Join`" method I see exactly opposite: as reducing dependency between default values of `g` and `f` options. Whether `g` calls `f` is an implementation detail and should not be a concern for user of `g`. If changing default options of `f` changes behavior of `g`, it forces users of `g` to keep track of those implementation details.

Comment: In contrast in "`Join`" method, changing default option values of `f` does not change behavior of `g`. To change behavior of `g` you need to change options of `g` which means that default option values of `g` and `f` are decoupled.

Comment: Hi, @jkuczm. I think about your words. And don't quite agree. You are right, Join reducing dependency. But this reducing is not reasonable I think. Because `g` calls `f` to run. If `f` is changed, then the `f` that `g` called should automatically change, and this is what normal functions behave. However, the join approach make it abnormal, and set a trap.

Comment: If your function `f` is so fundamental that other functions are defined in terns of it, then why are you redefining it and adding options?  If `g` can take any options that `f` takes, then surely `Options[f]` should be defined before `Options[g]`.

Comment: Hi, @JasonB. I think "Options[f] should be defined before Options[g]" is a good practice. But it should not be a constrain I think.

Comment: @matheorem Whether such behavior is reasonable depends on context, I just wanted to note that I don't see behavior of "`Join`" method as a flaw, but more as a feature that can be used intentionally. This does not exclude existence of situations in which "`OptionsPattern`" method might be more reasonable. In "`OptionsPattern`" method, fact that `f` accepts also options of `Plot` needs to be remembered when calling `f`. "Can *Mathematica* automatically remember this fact for us?" is, I think, very good question, and this is how I read your post.

Comment: @jkuczm Yeah, You are right. This is what I was thinking.

Comment: @matheorem Call me a crazy newbie lunatic (which I might be), but why not do some smart options management? For example, define all `Options` in one cell at the top, starting with symbols having no dependencies. Now place all definitions in any cell below them, this way `Options `are easier to manage because you can see dependencies right away, resulting in no breaks in continuity. Similarly, you can do this with definitions. It has worked for me so far, or is this a bad practice? I'm really asking!