# Clean and handy Options management/filtering

Tags: function-construction, options, filtering

#### the case

I want to be able to create a **function with some default options** but also without need to add full explicit list of options available for it.

And then inside I want to be able to **filter from given and default options, those which are Button options or Tooltip options** for example.

So something like:

```
Options[f] = {(*list of default options*)}

f[args__, OptionsPattern[]]:=Column[{
   (*Options that are suitable for Button*),
   (*Options that are suitable for Tooltip*),
   OptionValue[(*specific name*)]
 }]
```

And I wasn't able to get this with built in Options management functions: `OptionsPattern[]`, `OptionValue`, `FilterRules` etc.

#### additional requirements

1. I want to **avoid `Options[f] = Join[customOptions, Options[Button], ...]`**.

   I don't think is a good solution, there may be duplicates in `customOptions` for them and an explicit list of `Options[f]` grows.
2. I want to **be able to provide any option to the function** without error messsage e.g.: `Unknown option Apparance for f...`
3. We can get 2. by skipping `OptionsPattern[]` in definition but without it we can't use built in `OptionValue`.  I want to **be able to refer to functions by their names**.
4. **Rules filtering mechanism should not produce duplicates**. I know `Button[..., ImageSize->300, ImageSize->200]` will behave stable but I find it ugly.

#### my approach

```
(* auxiliary functions *)

mergeRules = GatherBy[Join[##], First][[All, 1]] &;

optionValue = #2 /. # &;

(* function definition *)

ClearAll[f];
Options[f] = {"Test" -> 1, ImageSize -> 100, TooltipDelay -> 20};

f[x_, optionsPattern : (_Rule | _RuleDelayed) ...] := With[{
   opt = mergeRules[{optionsPattern}, Options[f]]}
  ,
  Column@{
    FilterRules[opt, Options@Button],
    FilterRules[opt, Options@Tooltip],
    optionValue[opt, "Test"]
    }
  ]
```

So I need to start my definitions with `With[{  opt = mergeRules[ {optionsPattern}, Options[f]]}`, which does not seem to be a big problem, but why I have to do this?

#### tests

```
f[1, Appearance -> "Palette"]
```

> ```
> {Appearance->Palette, ImageSize->100} 
> {TooltipDelay->20}
> 1
> ```

```
f[1, ImageSize -> 200]
```

> ```
> {ImageSize->200}
> {TooltipDelay->20}
> 1
> ```

```
f[1]
```

> ```
> {ImageSize->100}
> {TooltipDelay->20}
> 1
> ```

#### question

Is there simpler approach, with built functions maybe? Or should I include `Options[Button]` etc. to `Options[f]` and count on the fact that when given duplicates, first one wins?

#### Edits

Mr.Wizard's answer fulfills points:

1 automatically, 2/3 by using `OptionsPattern[{f,Button, ...}]`. So still 4 needs custom filtering function but it is a good answer anyway.

Comment: Related: [(353)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/353/121),
[(20470)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20470/121)

Comment: FWIW I believe you could also use `mergeRules = DeleteDuplicatesBy[First]` (just a small comment.)

Comment: @Pickett Thanks for pointing this out. However, I would like to avoid functions introduced in V10 so it can be useful for more people.

Comment: @Pickett I forgot about that function.  I guess I put it out of mind when I didn't like the performance. :-/

Comment: I prefer using `Options[f] = fullList`. I find it annoying when I use `Options[f]` and get back an incomplete or empty list.

Answer (score 12):

Following your clarification this seems to be OK, though I would agree that a cleaner solution would be nice:

```
Options[f] = {foo -> bar, ImageSize -> 333};

f[args__, opts : OptionsPattern[{f, Button, Tooltip}]] :=
 Append[
   FilterRules[{opts, Options @ f}, Options @ #] & /@ {Button, Tooltip},
   OptionValue[foo]
 ] // Column
```

Test:

```
f[1, 2, Background -> Blue, AutoAction -> False, TooltipDelay -> 1]
```

> ```
> {Background -> RGBColor[0, 0, 1], AutoAction   -> False, ImageSize -> 333}
> {Background -> RGBColor[0, 0, 1], TooltipDelay -> 1}
> bar
> ```

---

Following your updated requirements the only streamlining I can think to recommend is to combine the functionality of your `mergeRules` with that of `FilterRules`.  This is a trivial refactoring but again I hope you find some value in the idea.

```
getRules[base_Symbol, op___][target_Symbol] :=
  First /@ GatherBy[{op, Options @ base} ~FilterRules~ Options[target], First]

Options[f] = {foo -> bar, ImageSize -> 333};

f[args__, opts : OptionsPattern[{f, Button, Tooltip}]] := 
 Append[getRules[f, opts] /@ {Button, Tooltip}, OptionValue[foo]] // Column
```

test:

```
f[1, 2, Background -> Blue, AutoAction -> False, TooltipDelay -> 1, ImageSize -> 99]
```

> ```
> {Background -> RGBColor[0, 0, 1], AutoAction   -> False, ImageSize -> 99}
> {Background -> RGBColor[0, 0, 1], TooltipDelay -> 1}
> bar
> ```

`getRules` could also be written with [`KeyTake`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/KeyTake.html)

```
getRules[base_Symbol, op___][target_Symbol] :=
  {op, Options @ base} // Flatten // KeyTake[Keys @ Options @ target] // Normal
```

Comment: Should I live with `Button[...., ImageSize->200, ImageSize->333]`?, it is ugly but works, could it be a problem anywhere?

Comment: @Kuba I don't recall ever seeing that syntax produce an error, and in fact I have found internal implementations that result in duplicate rules so it seems to be accepted practice at WRI; however I added a `GatherBy` filter for this case in my own code here: [(46925)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/46925/121)

Comment: More often than not, when two or more  option settings are given to a function, the leftmost one is the one applied, and the rest are ignored.

Comment: @J. M. Can you give me an example of the "not" case?

Comment: Wizard, sadly my memory fails me here. :( But at least for all the usual system functions, the "often" is in fact "always".

Comment: @J. M., @Mr.Wizard `Options[f] = {a -> x}; SetOptions[f, a -> y, a -> z]` uses the rightmost option.

Comment: @jkuczm I wouldn't say those are options for `SetOptions`, rather arguments. But good point.

Comment: @Kuba I agree, but I was bitten by it one time. I was aggregating options like this `newOpts = {opt -> val, oldOpts}`. I thought `f[newOpts]` would work the same as `SetOptions[f, newOpts];f[]` (except obvious fact that the latter sets options permanently), but it doesn't.

Answer (score 9):

Let's start with slightly modified version of `mergeRules`, that takes into account fact that options can have symbolic or string names and `name -> val` is treated the same as `"name" -> val`:

```
ClearAll[symbolToName, deleteOptionDuplicates]

symbolToName[sym_Symbol] := SymbolName[sym]
symbolToName[arg_] := arg

deleteOptionDuplicates[opts:OptionsPattern[]] :=
    GatherBy[Flatten[{opts}], Composition[symbolToName, First]][[All, 1]]
```

Now we can define an environment, providing special option-filtering function:

```
ClearAll[withOptions, getOptions]
withOptions[base_Symbol, opts___] :=
    Function[body,
        With[{allOptions = deleteOptionDuplicates[opts, Options[base]]},
            Block[{getOptions = FilterRules[allOptions, Options[#]] &},
                body
            ]
        ],
        HoldFirst
    ]
```

To make our environment easier to use, in function definitions, let's add some macro tricks [stolen from Leonid](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/10451/14303):

```
withOptions /: 
    Verbatim[SetDelayed][lhs_, rhs : HoldPattern[withOptions[__][_]]] :=
        Block[{With},
            Attributes[With] = {HoldAll};
            lhs := Evaluate[rhs]
        ]
withOptions /: 
    Verbatim[SetDelayed][
        h_[pre___, optsPatt_OptionsPattern, post___],
        HoldPattern[withOptions[body_]]
    ] :=
        h[pre, opts : optsPatt, post] := withOptions[h, opts][body]
withOptions /: 
    Verbatim[SetDelayed][
        h_[
            pre___,
            namedOptsPatt:Verbatim[Pattern][optsName_, _OptionsPattern],
            post___
        ], 
        HoldPattern[withOptions[body_]]
    ] :=
        h[pre, namedOptsPatt, post] := withOptions[h, optsName][body]
```

I guess that extraction of `OptionsPattern` from lhs could be more general.

Now we can define functions like this:

```
ClearAll[f]
Options[f] = {"Test" -> 1, ImageSize -> 100, TooltipDelay -> 20};
f[x_, OptionsPattern[{f, Button, Tooltip}]] :=
    withOptions@Column@
        {getOptions[Button], getOptions[Tooltip], OptionValue["Test"]}
```

It gives expected results:

```
f[1, Appearance -> "Palette"]
```

> ```
> {Appearance->Palette, ImageSize->100} 
> {TooltipDelay->20}
> 1
> ```

```
f[1, ImageSize -> 200]
```

> ```
> {ImageSize->200}
> {TooltipDelay->20}
> 1
> ```

```
f[1]
```

> ```
> {ImageSize->100}
> {TooltipDelay->20}
> 1
> ```

If there are duplicates, first option is used regardless of whether it's name is a symbol or a string:

```
f[1, "ImageSize" -> 1, ImageSize -> 2, ImageSize -> 3]
```

> ```
> {ImageSize->1}
> {TooltipDelay->20}
> 1
> ```

---

Usually I don't need to store or return filtered options, I just want to pass them to appropriate function.
In such cases other environment, that setts default option values for some functions, can be useful:

```
ClearAll[withDefaultOptions]
withDefaultOptions[base_Symbol, targets:{__Symbol}, opts___]:=
    Function[body,
        With[{allOptions=deleteOptionDuplicates[opts, Options[base]]},
            Internal`InheritedBlock[targets,
                Scan[
                    SetOptions[#, FilterRules[allOptions, Options[#]]]&,
                    targets
                ];
                body
            ]
        ],
        HoldFirst
    ]
withDefaultOptions /:
    Verbatim[SetDelayed][
        lhs_,
        rhs:HoldPattern[withDefaultOptions[_, _, ___][_]]
    ] :=
        Block[{With},
            Attributes[With]={HoldAll};
            lhs := Evaluate[rhs]
        ]
withDefaultOptions /:
    Verbatim[SetDelayed][
        h_[pre___, optsPatt_OptionsPattern, post___],
        HoldPattern[withDefaultOptions[body_]]
    ] :=
        h[pre, opts:optsPatt,post] :=
            withDefaultOptions[
                h,
                Cases[Flatten[{First[optsPatt]}], Except[h, _Symbol]],
                opts
            ][body]
withDefaultOptions /:
    Verbatim[SetDelayed][
        h_[
            pre___,
            namedOptsPatt:Verbatim[Pattern][optsName_, optsPatt_OptionsPattern],
            post___
        ],
        HoldPattern[withDefaultOptions[body_]]
    ] :=
        h[pre, namedOptsPatt, post] :=
            withDefaultOptions[
                h,
                Cases[Flatten[{First[optsPatt]}], Except[h,_Symbol]],
                optsName
            ][body]
```

Let's start with a dummy function, to which we'll pass options:

```
ClearAll[f];
Options[f] = {"optA" -> "valFA", "optB" -> "valFB"};
f[OptionsPattern[]] := OptionValue[{"optA", "optB"}]
```

Now a function that can accept and pass options to `f`. It has its own options and some overridden `f` options, with different defaults.

```
ClearAll[g];
Options[g] = {"optA" -> "valGA", "optC" -> "valGC"};
g[OptionsPattern[{g, f}]] :=
    withDefaultOptions@{OptionValue[{"optA", "optC"}], f[]}
```

Notice that we don't have to pass anything to `f`, in body of `g`. Proper default options for `f` are set automatically, by `withDefaultOptions`, based on what is matched by `OptionsPattern` and what is inside `OptionsPattern`.

If option for `f` is neither given explicitly, nor set as default on `g`, then default of `f` is used.

```
g[]
(* {{"valGA", "valGC"}, {"valGA", "valFB"}} *)

g["optA" -> 1]
(* {{1, "valGC"}, {1, "valFB"}} *)

g["optB" -> 1]
(* {{"valGA", "valGC"}, {"valGA", 1}} *)

g["optC" -> 1]
(* {{"valGA", 1}, {"valGA", "valFB"}} *)
```

Comment: I'll be honest: `withOptions` is more fluff than I care for.  However `withDefaultOptions` is a bloody brilliant idea!

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I agree concerning `withOptions`. Actually I had `withDefaultOptions` ready. `withOptions` was created just to show this macro/environment idea while fulfilling requirements from question.

Comment: Why do you wrap `Verbatim` around `SetDelayed`? I wouldn't have expected `SetDelayed` to evaluate prematurely here.

Comment: @bdforbes Honestly, I mindlessly copied it from `LetL` macro. Since it's also used in built-in ``Macros`DeclareMacro``, I thought there must be some subtlety that I'm missing, but you are right that everything seems to work the same without this `Verbatim`.