# Remove duplicate rules in a list?

Tags: rule

`Replace` and `ReplaceAll` apply rules only once, so multiple (redundant) rules can be given as input and the first instance of a rule is the only one that is applied.

How can I go about creating a function `simplifyRules` that can be given a list of rules and a relevant function (Replace, ReplaceAll, ReplaceRepeated, etc.) which returns a modified rules list without rules which are not applied by the function?

For example:

```
rules = FilterRules[{ImageSize->{Automatic, 300}, Scrollbars->{False, True}}~Join~Options[Pane], Options[Pane]];

simplifyRules[rules,ReplaceAll]
(* {ImageSize->{Automatic,300},
    Scrollbars->{False,True},
    Alignment->{Automatic,Automatic},
    Appearance->Automatic,
    AppearanceElements->Automatic,
    BaselinePosition->Automatic,
    BaseStyle->{},
    ContentPadding->True,
    DefaultBaseStyle->Pane,
    Enabled->Automatic,
    FrameMargins->Automatic,
    ImageMargins->0,
    ImageSizeAction->Automatic,
    ScrollPosition->{0,0},
    StripOnInput->False} *)
```

Comment: `Merge[ First ]`

Comment: Related: [(82626)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/82626/121)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's suppose you have:

```
rules = {1 -> "a", 1 -> "b", 1 -> "c", 4 -> "d", 2 -> "e", 3 -> "f"};
```

The only replace operation in which `1 -> "b", 1 -> "c",` are used is [`ReplaceList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceList.html):

```
ReplaceList[1, rules]
```

> ```
> {"a", "b", "c"}
> ```

For other operations you can in recent versions [`Merge`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Merge.html) as [Kuba](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5478/kuba) commented, or use [`DeleteDuplicatesBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeleteDuplicatesBy.html).

```
Merge[rules, First] // Normal

DeleteDuplicatesBy[rules, First]
```

> ```
> {1 -> "a", 4 -> "d", 2 -> "e", 3 -> "f"}
>
> {1 -> "a", 4 -> "d", 2 -> "e", 3 -> "f"}
> ```

(The output of `Merge` is an [`Association`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Association.html) which in may places can be used like a `Rule` list, but I added [`Normal`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Normal.html) for fully compatible results.)

However for backward-compatibility and possibly [better performance](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/55294/121) too I propose [`GatherBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GatherBy.html):

```
GatherBy[rules, First][[All, 1]]
```

> ```
> {1 -> "a", 4 -> "d", 2 -> "e", 3 -> "f"}
> ```