# Function which can take custom options and also accept options for functions that it calls

Tags: options

Consider a function `myFunc` with options

```
Options[myFunc] = {TellNoOne->True}; (* myFunc has some options *)

myFunc[a_, b_, OptionsPattern[]] := 
  Module[{},
    (* Do stuff with OptionValue[TellNoOne] and plot result *)
    ListPlot[{a,b}, moreOptions] (* want to pass some options to ListPlot here *)]
```

I wish to pass options that will target `myFunc`, like `TellNoOne`, and I also want to be able to pass any option to `ListPlot` that it accepts such as `PlotRange->All` and others.

Function call example:

```
myFunc[1, 3, TellNoOne -> False, PlotRange -> All, Joined -> True, Framed -> True]
```

How can I pass `myFunc` is own options plus others for `ListPlot`?

Comment: Does `myFunc[a_, b_, OptionsPattern[Join[Options[myFunc], Options[ListPlot]]]] := (* stuff *)` work for you?

Comment: You can use `FilterRules` like in this example from the documentation `FilterRules[{PlotRange -> 3, MaxIterations -> 5}, Options[Plot]]`

Comment: I thinks this is what you ask and more: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/82626/5478

Comment: [Does this answer your question?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/140912/12) Let us know if it's a suitable duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a very general approach in which we give `myFunc` default options from `ListPlot` as well as it own option `"Tell"`, which when given will cause a story :-) to be printed.

```
ClearAll[myFunc]
Options[myFunc] = {PlotStyle -> Red, Joined -> True, "Tell" -> False};
myFunc[data_List, opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=
  (If[OptionValue[myFunc, FilterRules[{opts}, Options[myFunc]], "Tell"], 
     Print["Once upon a time in a galaxy far, far away ...."]];
   ListPlot[data, FilterRules[{opts, Options[myFunc]}, Options[ListPlot]]])
```

#### Tests

Test data

```
data = Table[Sin[2 π t], {t, 0, 1, .02}];
```

Default options

```
myFunc[data]
```

[image: plot1]

Giving the "Tell" option

```
myFunc[data, "Tell" -> True]
```

[image: plot2]

Over-riding `myFunc`'s specified graphics options defaults and adding an additional graphics option

```
myFunc[data, PlotStyle -> Blue, Joined -> False, DataRange -> {0, 1}]
```

[image: plot3]

Comment: This works just fine. Thank you. I see by the other answers that there are a few variations on how it can be done.