# What is the difference between `OptionsPattern` and a sequence of `Rule` in a pattern?

Tags: function-construction, options, function-comparison

I'm experimenting with options. In my first tests, I wrote something like that to capture the options given to a function:

```
f[opts___Rule]:= {opts}
```

I later descovered [`OptionsPattern`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OptionsPattern.html):

```
f[opts:OptionsPattern[]]:= {opts}
```

Both seems to do the same thing and will produce the same result:

```
f[]
f[a->1]
f[a->1,b->2]
```

> ```
> {}
> {a->1}
> {a->1,b->2}
> ```

What are the pro and cons of using `opts:OptionsValues` instead of `opts___Rule` to capture the options given to a function?

Comment: `OptionsPattern` also accepts `RuleDelayed` and (nested) lists of rules. Furthermore it is clearer in intent and has very useful extra functionality when combined with [`OptionValue`](https://refernce.wolfram.com/language/ref/OptionValue.html)

Comment: That's a good point @Lukas. Maybe you should consider posting that as an answer?

Comment: I agree with Lukas's note that the `OptionsPattern[]`/`OptionValue[]` combo is quite powerful compared to the old method, but the first approach can be made more general: `f[opts___?OptionQ]:= {opts}`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @J.M. Before asking I made some researches. And I occasionally saw mention of the "old way" and the "new way" of dealing with options. But without further details. For seasoned Mathematica users, that should make sense. But for me, it's a little bit confusing. What's so powerful with the "new way"? What was wrong with the "old way"? To take the same wording as in the question, those are the kind of "pros and cons" I'm looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When [`OptionsPattern`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OptionsPattern.html) is combined with [`OptionValue`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OptionValue.html) you get filtering and warning of improper options:

```
Options[f] = {a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3};

f[OptionsPattern[]] := {OptionValue[b]}

f[a -> 7, x -> 5]
```

> OptionValue::nodef: Unknown option x for f. >>
>
> ```
> {2}
> ```

You can also adopt options for/from other functions, e.g.:

```
f[OptionsPattern[{f, Plot}]] := {OptionValue[b], OptionValue[PlotStyle]}

f[b -> 6, PlotStyle -> None]
```

> ```
> {6, None}
> ```

Additional examples:

- [Function with custom Options and modified Options for built-in Symbols](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20470/121)
- [Functions with Options](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/353/121)